# Unique issue with regex

Tags: php, regex

I have really strange issue with regex, I am testing using [LINK](http://phptester.net/)
Please only test there as it works exactly the same as on my machine.
I should be able only to see following text: "Audit Note by 3 4 5 6 7" But I can see an empty array. I know that this code works on regex101.com Please help

[Regex LINK](https://regex101.com/r/sSg4gb/6)

```
$string = "1

2

Audit Note by 3
4 
5
6
7

I don't need this line

I don't need this line
";

preg_match("/^Audit Note by(.*$)^$/ms",$string, $nmatch);
echo $nmatch[0];
```

Comment: paste us the regex101 link

Comment: Regex Link https://regex101.com/r/sSg4gb/6

Comment: Dupe of [Regex not working on my server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46339811/regex-not-working-on-my-server).

Comment: yes but this is solved and not not blocked!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using `^$` to match a new line you can use `\R` and use this code:

```
$string = "1

2

Audit Note by 3
4
5
6
7

I don't need this line

I don't need this line
";

preg_match('/^(Audit Note by.*?)\R\R/ms',$string, $nmatch);
echo $nmatch[1];
```

`\R\R` matches 2 consecutive line breaks of any type.

**Output:**

```
Audit Note by 3
4
5
6
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's your updated regex: https://regex101.com/r/sSg4gb/7

```
$string = "1

2

Audit Note by 3
4 
5
6
7

I don't need this line

I don't need this line
";

preg_match("#Audit Note by [\d.\s]*#",$string, $nmatch);
echo($nmatch[0]);
```

This outputs:

```
Audit Note by 3 
4 
5 
6 
7
```

Check it out here: https://3v4l.org/hiXpY

Comment: @user974435 Why you need phptester to test it? Maybe its deprecated or incompatible version. All answers here work.

Comment: Thats the problem mate. None of the answer works on my server or localhost, I run php 5.6 and in both places it's not working well. is there is something on the server or php settings to change?

Comment: you dont need php tester, look at what 3v4l said "Output for 5.6.0 - 5.6.30, hhvm-3.18.4 - 3.21.0, 7.0.0 - 7.2.0rc2"

Comment: That's the only please for me to show you how I can see it on my computer :) It's not the case for me that this is working online, I need this to be working on my server and local computer.

Comment: I tested delboy1978's code with phptester too and it's working. No idea why it wouldn't

Comment: This regular expression is very different from the one OP provided though... This one does not attempt to find an empty line, but simply matches digits and whitespace.

Comment: The dot is a new line, check what the flags are on regex101 link

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
preg_match("/Audit Note by (\d+\s+)+/",$string, $nmatch);
echo $nmatch[0];
```

It gives me:

```
Audit Note by 3 4 5 6 7
```